# How can I perform an ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 text file conversion while not changing any characters that are already valid UTF-8

Tags: linux, conversion, unicode, text-editing, utf-8

Consider a text file that looks like this visually:

```
This’s ISO-8859-1
This’s UTF-8
```

Behind-the-scenes, the `’` curly quote character in the first line is encoded as ISO-8859-1, and the same `’` character in the second line is encoded as UTF-8

The file looks like this on `cat -v` (`-v` option displays unprintable characters):

```
$ cat -v testing.txt
ThisM-4s ISO-8859-1
ThisM-bM-^@M-^Ys UTF-8
```

The goal is to standardize the file to UTF-8, meaning the first line needs to change and the second line MUST NOT change.  However, if you attempt an ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion using `iconv`, `recode` and others, it'll corrupt the second line of the file by converting the UTF-8 `’` into gibberish characters

Here's an example using `iconv` demonstrating that the second line becomes mangled:

```
$ cat testing.txt | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8
This´s ISO-8859-1
Thisâ€™s UTF-8
```

`recode` behaves similarly, mangling the second line:

```
$ recode iso-8859-1..utf-8 testing.txt
$ cat testing.txt
This´s ISO-8859-1
Thisâ€™s UTF-8
```

What I'd like it to do is skip over conversion of the UTF-8 `´` character (but still pass it along to the output, DON'T strip it out), because it's already UTF-8, so there's no need to convert it

But I haven't found any way to do this

This simplified text file is just being used as an example -- need a solution that will work for much larger files as well

For example, a file might contain the  UTF-8 `’` character on line 30, 40, 100; and the ISO-8859-1 `’` character on line 50, 60, and 200.  A file might not contain any instances of the ISO-8859-1 `’` character (in which case no changes to the file are needed).  Safe to assume that the file will not contain both the ISO-8859-1 `’` character and the UTF-8 `’` character on the SAME line, if that makes the problem scope easier.

I looked at this question:  [How to recode to UTF-8 conditionally?](https://superuser.com/questions/116907/how-to-recode-to-utf-8-conditionally)

however it doesn't seem to account for the scenario where the file contains mixed ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8

and yes I know it's not a good idea to have mixed encodings in the same file

but it already happened years ago and the goal is to get it all cleaned up so it won't be a problem again

Comment: If the first line is in ISO-8859-1, then I assume it should look like `This´s`, rather than `This’s` (which is not convertible to ISO-8859-1)...

Comment: yeah they didn't look exactly the same

Comment: don't use `cat -v`. It's much easier for people to recreate the file if you use `od -c` or `hd` as they can use the hex editor directly. The `M-` notation isn't quite well known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's UTF-8 decoder can pass-through non-UTF-8 characters as special codepoints U+DC00 – U+DCFF (which are normally illegal in UTF-8). Afterwards they can be found and re-decoded as something else:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import re
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.input, "rb") as fh:
    buf = fh.read()
    buf = buf.decode("utf-8", errors="surrogateescape")
    buf = re.sub(r"[\udc00-\udcff]+",
                 lambda m: (m.group(0)
                             .encode("utf-8", errors="surrogateescape")
                             .decode("iso8859-1")),
                 buf)
    sys.stdout.write(buf)
```

You can also do it by hand:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input")
args = parser.parse_args()

def decipher_runes(fh):
    curr = None
    more = 0

    while buf := fh.read(1):
        ch = buf[0]
        if more == 0:
            # Expect a UTF-8 leading byte
            curr = bytearray([ch])
            if   ch & 0b10000000 == 0b00000000: more = 0
            elif ch & 0b11100000 == 0b11000000: more = 1
            elif ch & 0b11110000 == 0b11100000: more = 2
            elif ch & 0b11111000 == 0b11110000: more = 3
            elif ch & 0b11111100 == 0b11111000: more = 4
            elif ch & 0b11111110 == 0b11111100: more = 5
            else:                               more = -1
        else:
            # Expect a continuation byte
            curr.append(ch)
            if ch & 0b11000000 == 0b10000000: more -= 1
            else:                             more = -1

        if more < 0:
            more = 0
            yield curr.decode("iso8859-1")
        elif more == 0:
            yield curr.decode("utf-8")

    if more:
        yield curr.decode("iso8859-1")

with open(args.input, "rb") as fh:
    for ch in decipher_runes(fh):
        sys.stdout.write(ch)
```

Comment: This seems to work great.

Followup question.... I didn't mention this originally because I wanted to tackle one thing at a time but some of the files have Windows-1252 characters mixed in rather than ISO-8859-1... I don't think I have any files with both Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 (at least I really hope not) so I was planning on processing them separately

I assume I can make a Windows-1252 version of this just by updating the curr.decode lines?

Comment: Yeah, changing either script to `.decode("windows-1252")` or any other [Python codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) should do the job. (In fact this specific change should handle _both_ file types, as Windows-1252 is directly based on ISO-8859-1 with only the bytes 0x80–0x9F added, but nothing changed or removed – in other words, a file with both Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 intermixed is really just a Windows-1252 file.)

Answer (score 1):

.NET allows you to create a [custom encoder/decoder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#implementing-a-custom-fallback-strategy) for invalid characters beside the default options (throw exception on invalid characters or replace them with a user-specified string) so you can use any .NET based languages and write your own decoder to convert ISO-8859-1 characters to UTF-8. I've written a simple PowerShell script to do that. [Install PowerShell to Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2) if you don't have and save the below script as `convert.ps1`

```powershell
class Decoder88591FallbackBuffer : System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer {
    [char]$c; [int]$idx # Internal decoder state
    
    Decoder88591FallbackBuffer() { $this.Reset() }
    
    [bool] Fallback([byte[]]$bytesUnknown, [int]$index) {
        $this.idx = 1; $this.c = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($bytesUnknown[0])
        return $true
    }

    [char] GetNextChar() {
        if ($this.idx -eq 1) {
            $this.idx = 2; return $this.c
        }
        return 0
    }

    [bool] MovePrevious() {
        if ($this.idx -eq 2) { $this.idx = 1; return $true }
        return $false
    }

    [int] get_Remaining() {
        if ($this.idx -eq 0) {
            if ($this.c -eq 0) { return 0 } else {return 1 }
        }
        return 0
    }

    [void] Reset() { $this.c = 0; $this.idx = 0 }
}

class Decoder88591Fallback : System.Text.DecoderFallback {
    Decoder88591Fallback() {}
    
    [Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer] CreateFallbackBuffer() {
        return [Decoder88591FallbackBuffer]::new();
    }

    [int] get_MaxCharCount() { return 1; }
}

$enc = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(65001, `
    [Text.EncoderReplacementFallback]::new(), [Decoder88591Fallback]::new())
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -ge [version]"6.0") {
    $content = Get-Content -AsByteStream -Raw $args[0]
} else {
    $content = Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Raw $args[0]
}
Set-Content -Path $args[1] -Encoding UTF8 -Value ($enc.GetString($content))
```

Then run the command as

```
./convert.ps1 testing.txt testing_out.txt
```

If you want to make it work for Windows-1252 then just change `[char]::ConvertFromUtf32($bytesUnknown[0])` to `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString($bytesUnknown)[0]`

Sample output:

```
$ cat -v testing2.txt
ThisM-4s ISO-8859-1

Bx M-0 M-1 M-2 M-3 M-4 M-5 M-6 M-7 M-8 M-9 M-: M-; M- M-?
Cx M-@ M-A M-B M-C M-D M-E M-F M-G M-H M-I M-J M-K M-L M-M M-N M-O
Dx M-P M-Q M-R M-S M-T M-U M-V M-W M-X M-Y M-Z M-[ M-\ M-] M-^ M-_
Ex M-` M-a M-b M-c M-d M-e M-f M-g M-h M-i M-j M-k M-l M-m M-n M-o
Fx M-p M-q M-r M-s M-t M-u M-v M-w M-x M-y M-z M-{ M-| M-} M-~ M-^?

ThisM-bM-^@M-^Ys UTF-8

Bx M-BM-0 M-BM-1 M-BM-2 M-BM-3 M-BM-4 M-BM-5 M-BM-6 M-BM-7 M-BM-8 M-BM-9 M-BM-: M-BM-; M-BM- M-BM-?
Cx M-CM-^@ M-CM-^A M-CM-^B M-CM-^C M-CM-^D M-CM-^E M-CM-^F M-CM-^G M-CM-^H M-CM-^I M-CM-^J M-CM-^K M-CM-^L M-CM-^M M-CM-^N M-CM-^O
Dx M-CM-^P M-CM-^Q M-CM-^R M-CM-^S M-CM-^T M-CM-^U M-CM-^V M-CM-^W M-CM-^X M-CM-^Y M-CM-^Z M-CM-^[ M-CM-^\ M-CM-^] M-CM-^^ M-CM-^_
Ex M-CM-  M-CM-! M-CM-" M-CM-# M-CM-$ M-CM-% M-CM-& M-CM-' M-CM-( M-CM-) M-CM-* M-CM-+ M-CM-, M-CM-- M-CM-. M-CM-/
Fx M-CM-0 M-CM-1 M-CM-2 M-CM-3 M-CM-4 M-CM-5 M-CM-6 M-CM-7 M-CM-8 M-CM-9 M-CM-: M-CM-; M-CM- M-CM-?

$ cat testing2_out.txt
This´s ISO-8859-1

Bx ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿
Cx À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï
Dx Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
Ex à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï
Fx ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ

This’s UTF-8

Bx ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¾ ¿
Cx À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï
Dx Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
Ex à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï
Fx ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
```

Note that [`od -c`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or [`hd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) (included in most Linux distros by default) would be much better than `cat -v` because they allow easier examining of the byte values

```
$ hd testing.txt
00000000  54 68 69 73 b4 73 20 49  53 4f 2d 38 38 35 39 2d  |This.s ISO-8859-|
00000010  31 0a 54 68 69 73 e2 80  99 73 20 55 54 46 2d 38  |1.This...s UTF-8|
00000020  0a 0a                                             |..|
00000022

$ od -c testing.txt
0000000   T   h   i   s 264   s       I   S   O   -   8   8   5   9   -
0000020   1  \n   T   h   i   s 342 200 231   s       U   T   F   -   8
0000040  \n  \n
0000042
```

For more information read

- [Is there a such a thing like "user-defined encoding fallback"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25118364/995714)
- [Implementing a Custom Fallback Strategy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#implementing-a-custom-fallback-strategy)